Feature selection based on covariance or precision matrix
I was just reading about properties of precision matrix, and the one that surprised me the most was that if $|\Sigma^{-1}_{ij}|\gg0$ it means that even if we condition on all other features, features $i$ and $j$ are highly correlated
On the other hand, the correlation matrix only considers the two features, and check if they correlate
So my question is, should it be better to use the precision matrix to do feature selection, rather than the covariance?

Indeed the precision matrix as the inverse of the covariance matrix can be more informative than the covariance matrix for certain aspects of feature selection and understanding conditional dependencies. The precision matrix provides insights into conditional independence relationships between features due to the usual multivariate normal (MVN) distribution assumption. If the entry $(i, j)$ is large and significant in magnitude, it implies that there is a significant conditional dependency between features $$ and $j$, even when conditioning on all other features. Finally precision matrices are often sparse in practice, especially if the data has a pattern where many features are conditionally independent given the rest based on some common sense modeling, which can directly help to identify groups of features that are directly dependent.
In contrast, the covariance matrix only captures marginal correlations as you've already mentioned. If features $$ and $j$ are correlated, this may be due to a direct or an indirect relationship mediated by other features such as a backdoor confounding factor. The covariance matrix does not distinguish these cases. Some even advocate using precision matrix to define the width of MVN as an information form with advantages in Bayesian inference similar to feature selection as you observed.

Some authors advocate using the precision ${\textstyle \tau }$ as the parameter defining the width of the distribution, instead of the standard deviation ${\textstyle \sigma }$ or the variance ${\textstyle \sigma ^{2}}$. The precision is normally defined as the reciprocal of the variance... This choice is claimed to have advantages in numerical computations when ${\textstyle \sigma }$ is very close to zero, and simplifies formulas in some contexts, such as in the Bayesian inference of variables with multivariate normal distribution.


This is probably more an extended comment than an "answer".

What do you want to use your "features" for?  Are you in a discriminative framework, trying to separate data sources? Are you trying to generate synthetic data by mimicking features of observed data?
In this context, perhaps contemplate adversarial auto-encoders. One side generates data where all known features of synthetic data match the features of observed data. The other side discriminates data, attempting to find new features that distinguish "real" from "fake" data.
You may find the following papers interesting. The common theme is: when specifying a multivariate model, start with a maximum entropy distribution (a diagonal precision matrix), and add constraints iteratively when the synthetic data set feature distributions do not match the observed data set feature distributions.

Dempster, Arthur P. "Covariance selection." Biometrics (1972): 157-175. (read past the abstract, I find it completely misrepresents the article and demonstrated output)
Zhu, Song Chun, Yingnian Wu, and David Mumford. "Filters, random fields and maximum entropy (FRAME): Towards a unified theory for texture modeling." International Journal of Computer Vision 27 (1998): 107-126.
[my paper] Keane, Kevin R. "Portfolio Variance Constraints." ICPRAM. 2019. (my precision matrix / inverse correlation matrix punch line appears in eqn. 25)

